# MultiValueDictKeyError at /signup/ 'password11'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to signup user but getting some weird error.
please help me to solve it

This is my view file with the function named signup

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password11 = request.POST['password11']
        if password1==password11:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Username Taken')
                return redirect('/account')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Email Taken')
                return redirect('/account')
            else:
                user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email)
                user.save();
                auth.login(request,user)
                print('user created')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Password not Matching')
            return redirect('/account')
        return redirect('/')


    else:
        return render(request,'account.html')
```

And this is my signup file. I've save file with the name account.html.

```
<form id="regform" style="margin-top: -40px;" action="/signup/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="Password11">
                        <button type="submit" id="btn2">Register</button>
                        <div>
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <h6>{{message}}</h6>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        
                    </form>
```

Comment: It is `Password11` with an uppercase, not `password11`.

Comment: But I would strongly advice to use a `Form` to process request data, and not do this manually, since a user can "forge" a POST request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working. And thanks for the advice I will try to use 'Form' to process request data.